# This is not set in my template?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a problem what looks like that this is not being set within my template. This didn't happen before, and I don't know what is changed.

My router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('gameRoom', {
    path : '/game/:_id',
    controller : GameRoomController
  });
```

Controller

```
GameRoomController = RouteController.extend({
  template : 'DetailsSubmit',

  waitOn : function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('gameList', this.params._id),
      Meteor.subscribe('gameInfo', this.params._id),
      Meteor.subscribe('hintsList', this.params._id),
      Meteor.subscribe('guessList', this.params._id),
      Meteor.subscribe('imagesList', this.params._id),
      Meteor.subscribe('allUsers')
//            Meteor.subscribe('scoreList', this.params._id)
// stil in development will optimize this later
    ];
  },

  data : function() {
    return Games.findOne(this.params._id);
  }
});
```

So in my detailsubmit.html I have the following template (snippit)

```
<template name='DetailsSubmit'> 
    {{#if isWaitingOnAction}}
        <div id="profileInfo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt=""/>
        </div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

If i type Games.find().fetch() it will output correctly:

```
_id: "5DDCNfWiBeHG4o7nQ"
active: true
finished: false
players: Array[2]
round: 0
theBoss: "JLApNut5rTpRxoL9S"
thePlayer: "o5aJETfWQTjEkZprf"
__proto__: Object
```

So I would expect my template would work correctly if I try one of the following commands:

And my helper:

```
Template.DetailsSubmit.helpers({

 isWaitingOnAction: function() {
        console.log(this) // return Object {} 
        console.log(Games.findOne(this._id)) // returns undefined in console
        console.log(Meteor.userId()); // returns correct userId 

    }
})
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post the relevant publish functions?

Comment: I've not optimized anything yet, so my publish function is very broad. It's publishing the whole game collection. Meteor.publish('gameList', function () {
    return Games.find();
});

Comment: Sometimes you reference template `DetailsSubmit` but the template is called `Detailsubmit`. Is it actually like that, or is that just how you posted it here?

Comment: Just how I posted it here. I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
return Games.findOne(this.params._id);
```

with:

```
return Games.findOne({_id:this.params._id});
```

Comment: @Kuba: these two statements are 100% equivalent.